# What does this program do? (arrays+functions)

Tags: c, arrays, function

I tried to run this code so many times, every time the output is just the same, I'm not getting, what's the use of such a code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
 void increment(int,int, int);
int main()
{
  int a[20],i;
  clrscr();
  printf("Enter array elements");
  for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);

  increment(a[0],a[5],a[2]);
  printf("After passing array:\n");

  for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    printf("%d\t", a[i]);

  getch();
  return 0;
}

void increment(int x, int y, int z)
{
  //int i;
  x++;
  y++;
  z++;
  //for(i=0;i<size;i++)
  // x[i]++;
}
```

Comment: `x++;` would not change `x`.  It'd compute and discard!

Comment: do you mean it's showing me that calling by value will never reflect that change?

Comment: For the use of this code, you should ask the person who wrote this code LOL, but it may help understand "pass by value" vs "pass by pointer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have any usefulness, the address of the values to be modified need to be passed to `increment()`, not the values themselves:

---

Change this:

```
void increment(int x, int y, int z)
    {
    //int i;
    x++;
    y++;
    z++;
    //   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    //   x[i]++;
    }
```

To this:

```
void increment(int *x, int *y, int *z)
    {
    //int i;
    (*x)++;  
    (*y)++;
    (*z)++;
    //   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    //   x[i]++;
    }
```

---

Then change this:

```
increment(a[0],a[5],a[2]);
```

to this:

```
increment(&a[0],&a[5],&a[2]);
```